# preferred way to schedule job @Scheduled vs crontab

Tags: cron, spring-scheduled

I have to run one utility periodically for instance say, every minute.
So, I have two option @Scheduled spring boot vs crontab of linux box that we are using to deploy the artifact.
SO, my question is which way should I use?
what are the pros and cons for each solution , any other solution if you can suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Just for comparing between these two, I don't have much points, but only based on this situation which I faced now. I just built a new end point and am doing performance testing and stress testing for the same on production. I am yet to decide the cron schedule times, and those may need a slight tweaking over some more time of observation. Setting via @Scheduled needs me to deploy/restart application every time I make a change.

Application restart generally takes more time than crontab edit.

Other than this, a few points considering the aspects of availability and scalability -

- Setting only via crontab on a single server would mean a single point of failure, if the server goes down.
- Setting via @Scheduled also could mean the same.
- If you have multiple instances of the server, this could mean endpoint getting triggered twice and you may not want to have the same. Worst case, is if the scaling up happens after a long time, and you wrote the @Scheduled endpoint long back, while it was only deployed on a single server and then you forgot. As soon as scaling up happens, the process will start getting hit twice.

So, none of these seem to be the best in terms of points of availability and scalability.
In such situations, ideally a distributed cron management system (I have heard about Rundeck) is needed, which manages which, out of the available servers is to be called to hit the desired end point and if needed to call the next server in case the first one is down. 
In case of any need for investigation. logs of rundeck could be checked to find the server which was actually called.

Comment: Avoiding multiple parallel executions when using `@Scheduled` can be archived with `@SchedulerLock ` (https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock)